# Installing Crypto++ 5.6.2 on Mac OS X

Tags: crypto++, failed-installation

I'm trying to installing Crypto++ 5.6.2 on my Mac. 
When I run

```
make -j4 libcryptopp.a"
```

I get the following error:

```
libtool: unrecognized option `-static'
libtool: Try `libtool --help' for more information.
make: *** [libcryptopp.a] Error 1
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: *"libtool: unrecognized option..."* - why is libtool rearing its ugly head? Crypto++ is not an autotools project. You `cd` into the project directory, and then you type `make static dynamic cryptest.exe`. Once it completes, you run `cryptest.exe v` to run the test suite. If there are no errors, then you install it with `sudo make install PREFIX=/usr/local/cryptopp/darwin` (or whatever location you prefer).

Comment: See the June 2015 update provided below.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone please help me with this?

There's a couple of things you can do to make this easier.

First, open [`GNUmake`](http://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/c5/GNUmakefile) and add `fPIC` on line 1:

```
CXXFLAGS = -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -fPIC
```

Second, open [`GNUmake`](http://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/c5/GNUmakefile) and drop *"version"* from the Clang detection logic on line 18:

```
CLANG_COMPILER = $(shell $(CXX) --version 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -i -c "clang")
```

Third, open [`GNUmake`](http://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/c5/GNUmakefile) and drop *GAS check* from around the Darwin flags around line 38. You want the Darwin check standing alone, without the `ifeq ($(GAS219_OR_LATER),0)` check.

```
ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
  CXXFLAGS += -arch x86_64 -arch i386
else
  CXXFLAGS += -march=native
endif
```

Fourth, open [`GNUmake`](http://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/c5/GNUmakefile) and add the following after the Darwin flags around line 45:

```
ifneq ($(CLANG_COMPILER),0)
  CXXFLAGS += -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-value
endif
```

---

With the makefile tweaked:

```
# Make the static lib, shared object, and test program
cd cryptopp
make static dynamic cryptest.exe
```

After make completes:

```
# Run the test program
cd cryptopp
./cryptest.exe v
```

After the validation suit completes successfully:

```
# Install into /usr/local
cd cryptopp
sudo make install PREFIX=/usr/local
```

---

OS X can be a real bear. It can be a bear because it silently ignores `LD_PRELOAD` (it uses `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead, see [`dyld(3)` man pages](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html)); it silently drops `-Wl,rpath`; it silently drops `-Bstatic`; and it always links to a shared object if available. It will link to the dynamic lib even on iOS, where its forbidden!

On OS X, It would behoove you you fully specify the static archive, and not use `-l` and `-L`. That is, use the following (this is from one of my test programs I use on OS X):

```
g++ -DDEBUG=1 -g3 -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter \
    -I/usr/local/include/cryptopp \
    cryptopp-test.cpp -o cryptopp-test.exe \
    /usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a
```

Its OK to fully specify `libcryptopp.a`. An archive is just a collection of object files, and you can specify object files for linking on the command line.

---

Here's a Pastebin of the GNUmakefile I use: [Crypto++ modified makefile for OS X and mobile](http://pastebin.com/d7G6PcEX).

---

**EDIT** (June 2015): Crypto++ is migrating away from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cryptopp/) to [GitHub](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp). Most of the changes discussed above have been Incorporated into the makefile.

Comment: After modifying the GNUmake I'm still getting the same error. Please help.

Comment: Re-download the library. If you unzip it manually, then use `unzip -a`.

Comment: The detailed explanation about make parameters is very helpful.